# Scraping .net (ajax) pages

Tags: php, html, .net, curl

I am building a PHP based scraper for a local search engine. Many .net websites are using ajax `(_dopostback)` to navigate through the content without a query submission:

```
javascript:_dopostback('content','page#')
```

Also there are hidden values that can be extracted `__EVENTTARGET`, `__EVENTARGUMENT` & `__VIEWSTATE`

I have tried to post them with `cURL` but I failed. I can only get the first page contents, but not all or move next. Any help or ideas are appreciated.

Comment: If content is generated via Javascript you're going to need something that knows how to run Javascript.  I'd recommend using a browser with a custom plugin or something